# kafka + Query the detailed configuration of all Topics

Tags: apache-kafka

we have kafka linux server with kafka version 2.6

I want the details about the Query of all Topics configuration

I am using `bootstrap-server` flag

here my approach  ( `172.23.248.85` is Kafka IP )

```
 kafka-configs.sh --describe --bootstrap-server 172.23.248.85:6667 --entity-type topics
Dynamic configs for topic ggt_opl are:
Error while executing config command with args '--describe --bootstrap-server 172.23.248.85:6667 --entity-type topics'
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support DESCRIBE_CONFIGS
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:104)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:272)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.getResourceConfig(ConfigCommand.scala:543)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.$anonfun$describeResourceConfig$4(ConfigCommand.scala:504)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.$anonfun$describeResourceConfig$4$adapted(ConfigCommand.scala:496)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.describeResourceConfig(ConfigCommand.scala:496)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.describeConfig(ConfigCommand.scala:480)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.processCommand(ConfigCommand.scala:303)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.main(ConfigCommand.scala:96)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand.main(ConfigCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support DESCRIBE_CONFIGS
```

where I am wrong ?

other way that is working on my Kafka is:

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zoo_server:2181 --describe
```

but I want to know if we can get the described details with `--bootstrap-server`

we also try:

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server=172.23.248.85:6667 --describe
Error while executing topic command : The broker does not support DESCRIBE_CONFIGS
[2021-09-02 09:35:34,054] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support DESCRIBE_CONFIGS
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

but on other way the following option is working:

```
 kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server=172.23.248.85:6667  --list
```

so I not understand why ( `--list` ) works but ( `--describe` ) isn't ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--bootstrap-servers` + `--describe` uses the `AdminClient` class, which your brokers need to be a certain version to support, as the error says.

Related [KIP-133](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-133%3A+Describe+and+Alter+Configs+Admin+APIs) (implemented in Kafka 0.11, according to JIRA)

Comment: sorry not understand , do you mean we cant use bootstrap-servers?

Comment: Not with the version of Kafka servers you are running, no. Unless you need a specific CLI version, you should probably use the matching server versions for those as well (assuming you downloaded a different version)

Comment: Also, AFAIK, there is no command to get all topic configurations at once without looping over the list, then describing one-by-one